# server that supports Unix and TCP clients

Tags: c, sockets, unix, server, client

I'm making a server/client program in C (LINUX). I have 4 programs in a folder. A clientUNIX, a clientTCP, a serverUNIX and a serverTCP. They all work flawlessly. Now, my goal is to make a server that supports both clients.

The easiest way of doing this, for me, was to start a new program (serverTCPUNIX) that does the following:

- In main(), create a thread to handle TCP clients and another thread to handle UNIX clients.

Is there a better way of achieving this? Because this way, I'd have 2 threads looping through clients. I want to know if I can have only 1 thread and 1 loop that supports both types of clients.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do determine if you can work with only 1 thread we would need to see what your current servers look like. Can they already handle multiple TCP connections with 1 thread?

Comment: Yes it can. The server gets into a loop, accepting client connections, and creating threads to handle them.

Comment: That means when you are talking about "only 1 thread", you actually mean "1 control thread and a number of other threads", correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right. What I meant was 1 thread accepting connections. Currently, I have 1 thread that only accepts TCP client connections, and another that only accepts UNIX client connections. Apart from those, I have 1 thread for each client, to handle them. What I want is to have only 1 thread that can accept both TCP connections and UNIX connections. Maybe use select(), but I don't really understand the use of it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could switch the sockets on the server to non-blocking mode and then use `select()` to wait for either of them to receive a connection and handle it as needed, for example by creating a thread handling the client's request, and then going back to same `select()` to wait for the next incoming connection.

Comment: Could you exemplify the use of select()? I know of its existance, but never understood what it really does.